# Image Sharing on Facebook from a page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, facebook

My webpage has an image slider. Each image comes with a FB share button. When i click on a share button i want the particular image to get posted along with the current URL. I have used the script below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function fbShare(url, title, descr, image, winWidth, winHeight) {
var winTop = (screen.height / 2) - (winHeight / 2);
var winLeft = (screen.width / 2) - (winWidth / 2);
window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=' + title + '&p[summary]=' + descr + '&p[url]=' + url + '&p[images][0]=' + image, 'sharer', 'top=' + winTop + ',left=' + winLeft + ',toolbar=0,status=0,width='+winWidth+',height='+winHeight);
}
</script>
```

But it does not select the image and is selecting some random text instead of the text in page body.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using meta tag? you can read description form the url :- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/web/tutorials/scrumptious/open-graph-object

Answer (score 0):

`sharer.php` only takes the URL as parameter, all other data (title, image, ...) will come from the Open Graph tags of that URL:

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=encodedurl
```

More information about Open Graph tags:

- http://ogp.me/
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/web/tutorials/scrumptious/open-graph-object

Comment: Thanks, the developer says this is supposed to work. I'll check with him again and let you know what happens.

Comment: the developer is wrong. it was working some years ago, but it only takes the url now.